# Initialising variables in awk

Tags: awk

What is the procedure for initialising variables in `awk` ?  I have read about the `BEGIN` clause in awk, which could be the appropriate way to initialise variables at the start.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Maybe a tutorial like [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-tutorial-understand-awk-variables-with-3-practical-examples/) helps?

Comment: Read the first few pages of the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Reading the tutorial, seems that awk `BEGIN` section is the way to initialise variables.  Although have seen that awk also casts undefined variables to `0` in a numeric context.  And to `""` in a string context.

Comment: or you can pass your variable with the assigned/initialized value on cli.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the variables in your code and if the default value of uninitialized variables is OK for your code.

Comment: Can you clarify which awk you are working with? While I guess some awk flavors may require variable initialization, I haven't come across one yet. Things like `seq 4 | awk '{ c++ } END{print c}'` work fine in `mawk` and `gawk` for example. What makes you feel you need to initialize a variable? Do you mean pass a set value when launching a command? Please [edit] your question and add some context.

Comment: I am using gnu awk.  A using a variable `display` such that when a condition is satisfied, all subsequent file reads use `display=1`.  Initially, `display` should be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to initialize variables for an `awk` script.  One way is to use the `-v` (for **v**ariable) switch.  For instance, `-vfoo=bar` will initialize the variable `foo` to the string `'bar'`:

```
$ awk -vfoo=bar 'END {print foo}' < /dev/null
bar
```

The other common way is to initialize your variables in a `BEGIN` stanza:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { foo="bar" } END { print foo }' < /dev/null
bar
```

In my opinion, the former is quite useful if your `awk` invocation is likely to require values which are variant based on the context at runtime, while the latter is better in cases where the initialized values are unlikely to need to be altered with each execution.